# Custom "Pro account" player for embedding videos uploaded via API

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

Is there any way of setting a custom player (already defined on a pro account) for embed videos uploaded via API?

Thanks,

Regards,

Marcelo

Comment: Are you asking for the way to get your custom player url (as found on vimeo.com) through the API?

Comment: What is the link in Vimeo to what you mention? May be we aren't talking about the same. I already used the api for getting the 'custom' player but it is the same. I think i need to set something when i upload the video using the API but i am not sure. This is the first time i use the API. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Vimeo API returns video file urls. You must combine those urls with your custom player on your own. Your custom player's documentation should have more information about this.

There is no way for the Vimeo API to automatically provide videos in the context of your player.